# node.js express html5 boiler build script?

Tags: node.js, express, boilerplate, build-script

I'm looking for something like the HTML5 boilerplate build script, but for node.js/express server.

Any such thing?

Thanks.

Comment: Check this link [Node boilerplate](https://github.com/mape/node-express-boilerplate)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `ant build` manually?

You can hook that into your IDE or you can hook it into `forever` or `supervisor` so that it builds before it restarts. And by hook I mean fork the source code and do it yourself.

What exactly do you expect express/node to automate for you?

Comment: isn't there a ton of webserver configs in boilerplate

Comment: @Mark As far as I know web server configs are auto generated with `express`. You get a whole bunch of `app.use` statements. Just create a new `express` project using the `express` cmd.